# Mule esb invoking web service error

Tags: mule

I exposed web service using CXF in mule esb, and trying to invoke some web service. Error that i get is **Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor**

configuration.xml:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8888" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="Calculator" port="ICalculator" serviceAddress="http://ws1.parasoft.com/glue/calculator" wsdlLocation="calculator.wsdl" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_Context" packageNames="com.saga.calculator" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
    <flow name="soaptestFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/soap" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.saga.service.WorkOrderNotification" doc:name="CXF"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="36d25e83-b7ad-48d8-aad0-779eb6ced53c" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload/>
            <dw:set-payload>
                <![CDATA[%dw 1.0
                         %output application/java
                         %namespace ns0 http://www.parasoft.com/wsdl/calculator/
                         ---
                         {
                            x: payload.task[0].externalSourceId as :number,
                            y: payload.task[0].externalSourceSystem as :number
                         }  as :object {
                            class : "com.saga.calculator.Add"
                        }]]>
            </dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="JAXB Object to XML"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.saga.calculator.CalculatorTransformer" doc:name="JavaTransformer"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="add" doc:name="InvokeCalculator"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Some help please

Comment: Looks like you havent attached your xml. Please attach it.

Comment: Please add your error stacktrace as well. If you are getting a timeout exception, it is highly likely that you have a proxy set up. Please check your config and add the proxy if necessary.

Comment: Thanks jvas, problem was with proxy set up.

Answer (score 0):

`<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8888" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" service="Calculator" port="ICalculator" serviceAddress="http://ws1.parasoft.com/glue/calculator" wsdlLocation="calculator.wsdl" doc:name="Web Service Consumer"/>
    <mulexml:jaxb-context name="JAXB_Context" packageNames="com.saga.calculator" doc:name="JAXB Context"/>
    <flow name="soaptestFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/soap" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.saga.service.WorkOrderNotification" doc:name="CXF"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="36d25e83-b7ad-48d8-aad0-779eb6ced53c" doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload/>
            <dw:set-payload>
                <![CDATA[%dw 1.0
                         %output application/java
                         %namespace ns0 http://www.parasoft.com/wsdl/calculator/
                         ---
                         {
                            x: payload.task[0].externalSourceId as :number,
                            y: payload.task[0].externalSourceSystem as :number
                         }  as :object {
                            class : "com.saga.calculator.Add"
                        }]]>
            </dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <mulexml:jaxb-object-to-xml-transformer jaxbContext-ref="JAXB_Context" doc:name="JAXB Object to XML"/>
        <custom-transformer class="com.saga.calculator.CalculatorTransformer" doc:name="JavaTransformer"/>
        <ws:consumer config-ref="Web_Service_Consumer" operation="add" doc:name="InvokeCalculator"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>`